# Best way to set up an android tablet as a touchscreen kiosk?

Tags: android, cordova, raspberry-pi, kiosk

**The Challenge:**

I'm working with a client to create a prototype for a fleet of touchscreen consumer point of sale kiosks. My first challenge is to create a touchscreen interface using a tablet that fulfills the following requirements:

- The tablet must only give access to our web app. I assume this will be done with a web view within an app. I could also be swayed into building a native app using Cordova.
- The tablet internet connection must be over ethernet/usb, no wifi/bluetooth can be used due to regulations. I plan to do this by connecting the tablet via usb to a raspberry pi with ethernet connected to it. The raspberry pi will also host a very simple local server and be a communication hub for a barcode scanner (for scanning products) and credit card scanner.
- In the event of a power outage, I would really like to have the tablet power up and launch the app without any human intervention when power returns. This allows us to know the kiosk will always operate without any help from staff. The device will also likely be in a locked enclosure preventing anyone from reaching any of the physical buttons.

I am not an android developer by any means, however I know that iPad will not work because you can not supply network connection over USB easily and cannot auto launch an app after power cycle.

**My questions:**

- What do I need to consider if I'm going to pull this off? Do I need to root each tablet and is that process going to be scalable for creating lots of these (~100) kiosks? I have found posts like [this one](http://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/) regarding how to put an android tablet into "kiosk mode". Seems like a good start.
- Is running this app in a web view a good approach or is a native app built with Cordova better approach. I am unlikely to build it in native SDK due to concerns with maintenance.
- Is it possible to power the tablet up automatically when power is present or does someone have to physically push the power button?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

> The tablet must only give access to our web app. I assume this will be done with a web view within an app. I could also be swayed into building a native app using Cordova.

For your app to be the only accessible app on the tablet, look into the new "Kiosk Mode" new with API 21 (5.0 or Lollipop).   If you are unable to use API 21, then you could potentially create a launcher app that disables the back button, the home button, and find a way to hide/disable the settings and notifications bars.

> The tablet internet connection must be over ethernet/usb, no wifi/bluetooth can be used due to regulations. I plan to do this by connecting the tablet via usb to a raspberry pi with ethernet connected to it. The raspberry pi will also host a very simple local server and be a communication hub for a barcode scanner (for scanning products) and credit card scanner.

It's pretty straightforward to programmatically turn off all wireless network connectivity with Android's system services.  For example:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Is all that would be needed to turn off WIFI (with the correct app permissions).

> In the event of a power outage, I would really like to have the tablet power up and launch the app without any human intervention when power returns.

As far as I know, the device turning back on without human intervention is impossible.  You will be able to have the app launch at start up by listening for the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.  If your app is the default launcher app, your app will be shown on startup.

In terms of rooting the device, this would be helpful as you would get more access to system level APIs.  For example, you could install your app as a system app and let it reboot the device automatically if it encounters major problems.